# Answer to the summation

Tags: summation

I have this summation
[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMCGl.png)

How did I get the RHS of answer?

Comment: Do you know the *geometric series*?

Comment: no i am new to summations

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I could not type the summation equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a real number $q$ with $|q|<1$ we have

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^n=\frac{1}{1-q}$ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^n=\frac{q}{1-q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $|q|<1$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}aq^{k-1}=\frac{a}{1-q}.$ Obesrve that the 2nd summation starts from $m=1$, so adapt this formula.